Why does asyncio/loop execute sequentially?
As a result of executing such code, the processing is carried out sequentially:
start = ticker_1  
finish = ticker_1  
start = ticker_2  
finish = ticker_2  
start = ticker_3  
finish = ticker_3  
etc.

import asyncio
import other_libs

tikers_list['tiker_1, tiker_2, tiker_3,...,tiker_n ']

#Worker
async def fn_load_and_calc(ticker,row_calc):
    print(f'start  = {ticker}')
    # The following operations are performed inside the function:
    # - Uploading quotes to the panda via API or Libs of the different data-providers.
    # - Adding fields to the panda table and filling them with calculated values.
    # - Saving the panda table to a csv and xlsx file.
    # - Displaying events in the command line.
    
    # The code completes execution after about 2 seconds
    print(f'finish = {ticker}')

#Variant 1
def make_asyncio():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    tasks=[]
    row_calc=0
    
    for ticker in tikers_list:
        row_calc+=1
        tasks.append(loop.create_task(fn_load_and_calc(ticker,row_calc)))
    
    wait_tasks = asyncio.wait(tasks)
    loop.run_until_complete(wait_tasks)
    loop.close()

make_asyncio()

#Variant 2 for the modern version of Python
def make_asyncio():
    row_calc=0
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        for ticker in tikers_list:
            row_calc+=1
            tg.create_task(load_and_calc(asset,ticker,row_calc,SCENARIO))
 
 asyncio.run(make_asyncio())

I expected to get something like this mixed execution:
start = ticker_1  
start = ticker_2  
finish = ticker_1  
start = ticker_3  
finish = ticker_2  
finish = ticker_3
etc.

What is my mistake?
Maybe it is executed sequentially because the same function (fn_load_and_calc) is called in asyncio task only with different arguments?
However, in the large number of examples that I found, this was not a problem.
For information. A variant using multiprocessing, ThreadPool ... it works as it should.
Maybe it is executed sequentially because the same function (fn_load_and_calc) is called in asyncio task only with different arguments? However, in the large number of examples that I found, this was not a problem.
Maybe instead of the fn_load_and_calc() function, I need to make a class and call its instances?

Are there any await-s in the fn_load_and_calc function?

No. Has not any await-s in the fn_load_and_calc function.

then the asyncio cannot be helpful. It does not run tasks in parallel, it can "only" do other work while waiting for something, most often for I/O. "Waiting" means the code is doing await <something-not-ready-yet> - this is also the only point in an async program, where tasks can be rescheduled.

@VPfB thanks. Now it's clear. Perhaps my task needs to be solved without asyncio.
